# How to use processing *.py files manually?

Tags: gdal, pyqgis, qgis-3

I want to rasterize vector layer by using Python code. On QGIS 3, there is no rasterize tool. Others are not applicable for me. However I found rasterize.py under this folder:

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\python\plugins\processing\algs\gdal\rasterize.py
```

Is there any way using these py file manually to rasterize vector layers?

**NOTE:**
I have already tried to define these parameters and run:

```
processing.runAndLoadResults('gdal:rasterize', parameters)
```

But it does not work!